# AlertDialog para seleção de Números

Tags: android, android-layout

eu to tentando fazer um AlertDialog ou algo parecido que resolva meu problema.
A questão é, preciso de algo parecido com a foto, onde eu possa utilizar o valor numérico que estiver selecionado. Talvez eu nao esteja pensando pelo caminho certo, então qualquer luz eu agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você precisa é de um NumberPicker.
Um exemplo de implementação
https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-numberpicker-in-android.html

Comment: Exelente isso mesmo